# Logic puzzles: Flags and Stripes

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle, pattern

#### Puzzle 1

[image: Puzzle 1: Colored Flagpoles]

#### Puzzle 2

[image: Puzzle 2: Letter Patterns]

##### Clues

The only instructions given to solve this is that the answer can be alpha-numeric text.

##### Ideas

- Puzzle 1:

  - 3 flagpoles seem to have top-balls (called a [truck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truck_(rigging))), while 3 don't
  - The colors in each flag I've found so far are (in hex and color-name, from top to bottom)

    - #808080: Gray
    - #7f00ff: Voilet
    - #c00000: Red
    - #3f8000: Avocado
    - #410080: Indigo
    - #ffffff: White
- Puzzle 2:

  - Can't think of a lot of ideas here, though it feels like I've encountered patterns like these before (2x2 grid with stripes of different orientations), probably in a logic puzzle-book years ago
  - There seems to be a co-relation between letters and (1) the position (within the 2x2 grid), (2) orientation (vertical/diagonal/horizontal) and (3) number of stripes (3/4/5)

###### Source

Posted in a private telegram group of puzzlers, will share a twitter handle of the puzzle-maker once they reply for credit

Comment: are the two puzzles completely independent? Or is the solution a combination of information from both diagrams?

Comment: @KateGregory Each puzzle is Independent